# Rotate SCNNode around parent's axis using an action

Tags: cocoa-touch, scenekit, scnnode

I have a bunch of SCNNode's that all share the same parent. I can rotate a group them around their own axes using

```
func handleTap(gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let sceneView = self.view as SCNView
    let action = SCNAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI_2), aroundAxis: SCNVector3Make(-1, 0, 0), duration: 1)
    let slice = self.cubes[18...26]

    for node: SCNNode in slice {
        node.runAction(action, completionHandler: { () -> Void in
            println("hmm")
        })
    }

}
```

But ideally what I would like to do is rotate them around their parent's axis instead. I can rotate the entire parent but that rotates many more nodes than I'd like, and I've tried grouping them into their own parent, but when I add them back to their previous parent they don't maintain their new position.

Comment: does it make sense to group all these nodes under a child node of the parent? The parent would have as child nodes the nodes that you want to move individually and that new "group" node. And under the "group" node you would find all the nodes that you want to move together.

Comment: The group of nodes that needs to rotate changes frequently, but yes, the solution I have right now groups them under a new node then rotates that node.

Comment: good. If you want to periodically reparent the nodes you can have a look at `-convertTransform:fromNode:` to preserve their world orientation.

Comment: I wish you would have told me that when I asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819698/node-groups-position-is-reset-at-the-start-of-scnnode-runaction) haha, took me a while to figure out