# How do I rotate a SCNNode without eulerAngles?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am trying to rotate a `SCNNode` with a `JoyStick` but when I use the `.eulerAngles` property the `SCNNode` doesn't seem to be affected by any physics. Thats why I want to use `angularVelocity` or `angularVelocityFactor`. Except there is another option.

Here I get the x and y values from my 2D `JoyStick` (touches moved function):

```
dx = base.position.x - ball.position.x
dy = base.position.y - ball.position.y
angle = atan2(dx, dy)
```

In the update function I set the velocity of the `SCNNode` (this is working):

```
playerNode.physicsBody!.velocity.x = Float(dx)/10
playerNode.physicsBody!.velocity.z = Float(dy)/10
```

What do I have to do to rotate my `SCNNode` in the same direction as the JoyStick.

Comment: What do you do that is not working? Have you read the documentation on [`SCNPhysicsBody`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody) and the **Physics and the Rendering Loop** chapter? It says that changing the transformation of a node resets its physics simulation and how to work around it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why SCNPhysicsBody resets position when set eulerAngles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092588/why-scnphysicsbody-resets-position-when-set-eulerangles)